# Parse full string in Html using C#

Tags: c#, html, parsing

I have the following two examples of html-

```
<a href="http://foo.com">User</a>: <a style="color:#333" href="http://foo.com/word"></a> blue elephant  &middot;

<a href="http://foo.com">User</a>: <a style="color:#333" href="http://foo.com/word">@<b>word</b></a> blue elephant  &middot;
```

I am trying to parse this using C# to put into a csv file and it is working to an extent however, when the html contains the '@' symbol in it, it will either leave the csv cell blank or not include the word with '@' before it. The main part I am trying to get is `@word blue elephant` however this is bringing back a blank cell, whereas the first html example brings back `blue elephant` as desired.

I am using the following technique to do this-

```
string[] comm = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(content[1], "<a");
```

How can I alter this to work for the second html example?

Comment: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use a proper HTML parser like the one in [HTML agility pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) in this situation (and save yourself from [invoking the wrath of Cthulhu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454))

Some examples of how to use it

- **[Getting started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack/847051#847051)**
- **[Easily extracting links from a snippet of html with HtmlAgilityPack](http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2009/11/easily-extracting-links-from-snippet-of.html)**

Comment: Ok thanks for the input, I presume my question would not be overly complex when using a tool like this?

Comment: No, it's pretty easy to use and understand, if your familiar with the structure of HTML documents. If you're not, you soon will be :)

Comment: I have mark your answer as useful, however will give full credit once I get my head around the agility pack thank you.